# Dynamically creating variables from Array into Ajax Success

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, variables

Hi have this `each` from an ajax call:

```js
$.each(data.my_json, function(i, item) {

    const op_id             = item.op_id;
    const op_name           = item.op_name;

    let  nv_tmp_totals      = item.nv_tmp_totals;
    let nvc_tmp_totals      = item.nvc_tmp_totals;
    let  iniz_totals        = item.iniz_totals;
    let deft_totals         = item.deft_totals;
    let rmkt_totals         = item.rmkt_totals;

    let nv_tmp_average      = item.nv_tmp_average;
    let nvc_tmp_average     = item.nvc_tmp_average;
    let iniz_average        = item.iniz_tmp_average;
    let deft_average        = item.deft_tmp_average;
    let rmkt_average        = item.rmkt_tmp_average;

})
```

I'd like to reduce my code using a loop for my variables. Obviously in this case the loop is repeated several times and does not work

```js
const source = ['rmkt', 'iniz', 'deft','nvc_tmp','nv_tmp'];

$.each(data.my_json, function(i, item) {

    const op_id         = item.op_id;
    const op_name       = item.op_name;

    for (let i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
                                    
        window[source[i]+"_totals"]  = parseFloat(item.source[i]+"_totals")
                            
        window[source[i]+"_average"]  = parseFloat(item.source[i]+"_average")
                                    
    }

})
```

Comment: What are you going to do with these variables? I bet there's a better approach to achieving the actual goal. Taken at face value, you'd need `item[source[i]]` but again, this is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```js
$.each(data.my_json, function(i, item) {
    Object.assign(window, item)
})
```

The `window` object will now have all the properties from `item`.

[MDN for Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)